# How does Azure ASR finds the IP Address of On Premise VM to be migrated?

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

Working on migrating the On-Premise servers to Azure using ASR.

But in few On-Prem servers which are having multiple IP addresses, the IP address of the On-Prem VM changes after discovery phase , that is, the IP Address supplied before discovery and IP Address provided by ASR after discovery phase are different.

Please help me with this. Like- How the ASR decides the IP Address of the On-Prem VM ? How the IP Address is getting changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration Server (CS) is the medium for communication and data replication between your on premise and Azure.

Process Server (PS) is by default installed on CS and saves source machine details. It also installs Azure Site Recovery Mobility Service on VMs you want to replicate, and performs automatic discovery of on-premises machines.

Mobility service captures data writes on the machine, and forwards them to the Site Recovery process server. PS does discovery of VMs in frequent intervals may be every (15 - 30) minutes which captures any change in IP of sources machines and replicates data continuously.

Note: The IP address of CS and PS remains same in most cases and doesn't change (static).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-architecture